# What is the term for shaking one's head when your hair is wet?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, verbs

I'm not a native speaker and just can't seem to think of the right term. 
What I want to describe is the movement when you're, for example, swimming and you come up for air and shake your head as if you wanted to get your wet hair out of the way or shake off the water running down your face if that makes sense. 
Similar to what dogs do when they're shaking off water. 
I don't know how to paraphrase that. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Headbanging**?

Comment: "He came to the surface and **shook the water from his hair.**"

Comment: *Shake* does the job.

Comment: You can **flick** your hair when it is wet (and long enough).

Comment: Agree with @Lawrence. I've had many dogs and taken many showers but can't come up with a better word than *shake*. It is what it is.

Comment: **Shake** is the only word I can think of for the *movement* you describe. If you're looking for a word to describe the *purpose* of all that **shaking**, it would be to **expel**: in **shaking**, a  dog is **expelling** water from its fur, and a swimmer is  **expelling** water from their hair or face.